# Zero-pad a date string without converting to a different type

Tags: c#, string

I have several dates in string form. I want to ensure they have the format `09/08/2012` even if they come in as `9/8/2012`.

I know that I could convert them to DateTime objects, then back to strings, and format them that way. This question comes from curiosity, not necessity.
I want to know if there's a way to do this without data transformations. My guess is that if it's possible it will use `string.Format()` method.

Is it possible to apply the zero-padded date format to a string without changing its type as part of the process?

Comment: I edited your question to remove the yes/no question into something more open-ended.  Asking a yes/no question *immediately* begs the question, "okay, how?"  Just skip that step and ask how.

Comment: The original phrasing of my question wasn't specific enough. I apologize to those people who have already answered for misleading you. I have edited my question to try to make my actual intent more clear.

Comment: Define what you mean by "intermediary step", and how does my answer not answer your question?

Comment: @Amy An intermediary step would be any step that doesn't return the desired final output. Your answer converts the string into an array that is processed before being converted back into a string. The conversion into the array is the intermediary step in that case.

Comment: Your edit didn't clarify anything.  It altered the meaning of the question.  No, there is no way of doing what you want without an "intermediary step"

Comment: @Amy The [original form of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/45763798/1) asked if it was possible to zero-pad the string without changing the type. Not changing the type was always there.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136370/who-else-thinks-that-editing-question-after-it-is-answered-should-be-prohibited/136371#136371

Comment: @Amy Like I said, I'm sorry that the original form of my question wasn't clear, but formatting the string without changing its type was always the core of the question.

Comment: Good luck doing this without any data transformations whatsoever.  You're going to need it.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy to do.

1. Split the string on the `/`.
2. Left-pad each section to 2 digits, prepending with '0' as needed.
3. Join the string parts back together

Code:

```
var x = "9/7/2017";
var parts = x
    .Split('/')                         //  <-- step 1
    .Select(y => y.PadLeft(2, '0'));    //  <-- step 2
var z = String.Join("/", parts);        //  <-- step 3

Debug.WriteLine(z);   // prints 09/07/2017
```

As you can see the code is *just* complicated enough to take a minute to read and understand.  It's clearer to simply parse the date into a `DateTime`, then reformat it into the desired format.

```
var x = "9/7/2017";
var z = DateTime.Parse(x).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

That's *much* easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could also split the string on "/" character and if check if the first string in resultant array has 1 character only, if so, add 0 to the front.

Answer (score 0):

The only data type in use is a string.

```
var x = "09/7/2017";
var y = x[1] == '/' && x[3] == '/' ? new string(new [] { '0', x[0], x[1], '0', x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7] }) 
      : x[1] == '/' && x[4] == '/' ? new string(new [] { '0', x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8] })
      : x[2] == '/' && x[4] == '/' ? new string(new [] { x[0], x[1], x[2], '0', x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6], x[7], x[8] })
      : x[2] == '/' && x[5] == '/' ? x
      : x;
```